# Missing descriptor exception while using Eclipselink Expressionbuilder

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have an entity **Person** with fields **String name** and **String designation**. When I tried to query using Eclipselink **ExpressionBuilder**, as:

```
    Project project=new Project();
    Login login=new DatabaseLogin();
    login.setUserName("root");
    login.setPassword("root");
    project.setLogin(login);
    DatabaseSession session=project.createDatabaseSession();

    ExpressionBuilder expBuilder=new ExpressionBuilder();
    Expression expression=expBuilder.get("name").equalsIgnoreCase("SomeName");
    Vector readAllObjects = session.readAllObjects(Person.class, expression);
```

On executing last statement the following exception is thrown :

**Exception [EclipseLink-6007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class com.mycompany.entity.Person].
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Person)**

What might be the reason? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I got it. Instead of DatabaseSession, org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession had to be used.

```
    JpaEntityManager jpaEntityManager=em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class);
    ClientSession session=jpaEntityManager.getServerSession().acquireClientSession();

    ExpressionBuilder expBuilder=new ExpressionBuilder();
    Expression expression=expBuilder.get("name").equalsIgnoreCase("SomeName");
    Vector readAllObjects = session.readAllObjects(Person.class, expression);
```

**em** is the EntityManager.

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add a descriptor for Person.  You need to map it to be able to query it.

Also consider using JPA.

Comment: Thanks..I saw this somewhere.But I am confused about how to do it.