# Facing Missing descriptor for [interface jakarta.persistence.Tuple] while using eclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I've been working of updating of code from hibernate to eclipselink . While running the test scenario i was facing below error which point to this query

```
   @Query(value = "SELECT distinct on (s.id) s.id as pId, CAST(s.data as TEXT), " +
            "s.created_at as createdAt, s.closed as closedAt, s.type as Type" +
            " FROM Stable s where s.status = 'CLOSED' order by s.id, s.created_at desc", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Project> getAll();
```

following is the exception

```
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [interface jakarta.persistence.Tuple].
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Tuple sql="******************")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.descriptorIsMissing(QueryException.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkDescriptor(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1195)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1283)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3025)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1841)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1823)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1788)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy168.getAllLatestFinishedSimulations(Unknown Source)
```

I tried some of the stackoverflow suggestions such as [Missing descriptor exception while using Eclipselink Expressionbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771561/missing-descriptor-exception-while-using-eclipselink-expressionbuilder)  , but it didnt help . Im not sure on what could be the reason for this as this particular query was working with hibernate but not with eclipselink . Please share your insights . Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure why Spring injects 'Tuple' into the createNativeQuery api when the JPA specification states it isn't supported, but Is there are reason you need a native query for this; You might be able to use JPQL. What versions of spring and EclipseLink are you using, as later versions might have added support.

Comment: We were using projection interface to fetch the data , hence the native query was used

Comment: Projection can use JPQL queries which won't have this issue.